# Asyntask with OnCreate action menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `OnCreateActionMenu` to share my values.I'm using `ShareContentprovider` method I pass the value through intent.But the problem is I want to get the value which is running in an `AsynTask`.So if it possible to use a goto like statement ? or any other way ? 
My code is

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share, menu);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


}
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
 // passing the username
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,""+name+"via Myapp");
    // passing ID 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,t1);
    return intent;

}
```

where t1 is the value from the `textField` generated after `AsynTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a reference to `mShareActionProvider` object, you can change its share intent whenever you want.

You can execute you `ASyncTask` and after completion, you can set the `shareIntent` again using something like this:

```
public boolean onPostExecute(String newString) {

    //newString here is the calculated String in ASyncTask
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent(newString));

}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    // passing the username
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,""+name+"via Myapp");
    // passing ID 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,newText);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Not at all. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has a API called onProgressUpdate(). Using this you can send the intermittent  progess values back to UI thread.

protected void onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)

Added in API level 3
Runs on the UI thread after publishProgress(Progress...) is invoked. The specified values are the values passed to publishProgress(Progress...).

protected final void publishProgress (Progress... values)

```
Added in API level 3
This method can be invoked from doInBackground(Params...) to publish updates on the UI thread while the background computation is still running. Each call to this method will trigger the execution of onProgressUpdate(Progress...) on the UI thread. onProgressUpdate(Progress...) will not be called if the task has been canceled.
```

Comment: yeah but how an I send the value to the Intent getDefaultShareIntent() method?

Comment: You can call your function getDefaultShareIntent() from inside onProgressUpdate() with proper value. Code inside onProgressUpdate  runs on UI thread.